# Spring Boot - Liquibase - takes a long time(60x) to execute occasionally

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

## Configuration

I am using Spring Boot `2.3.2.RELEASE` with `Liquibase` on the classpath.

`build.gradle 6.4.1:`

```
id 'org.liquibase.gradle' version '2.0.4'
implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.0.0'
```

`application.properties:`

```
spring.liquibase.changeLog=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
spring.liquibase.user=username
spring.liquibase.password=password
```

db.changelog-master.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<databaseChangeLog  
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"  
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">  
   <preConditions>
      <dbms type="oracle"/>
   </preConditions>
   
   <include file="db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.oracle.sql"/> 
</databaseChangeLog>
```

`db.changelog-1.0.oracle.sql:`

My sql file has only 8 changesets, which has all been ran previously(nothing new to run), such as:

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset author:date-1
--preconditions onFail:MARK_RAN
--precondition-sql-check expectedResult:0 SELECT count(*) FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'XXX';
SQL 1;
:
```

`DATABASECHANGELOG` table has the expected 8 entries.

## Issue

I face a delay issue occasionally, especially when i just start STS 4.5.1 IDE(connecting remotely to the DB via VPN), but when the application is rerun/restarted i do not face it *anymore* until some future time. I am not able to be more precise or reproduce the issue at will.

As such, i have set `logging.level.liquibase=DEBUG`, and this is where the *delay* is *happening*:

## Log with delay(~4 minutes)

> :
> 2020-07-27 12:55:33,015 [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator - Loaded liquibase.diff.compare.DatabaseObjectComparator instance com.datical.liquibase.ext.storedlogic.checkconstraint.CheckConstraintComparator
>
> 2020-07-27 <<<12:55:33,019>>> [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.util - Computed checksum for 1595825733018 as 2349116d802a7d8314d3cced0b6e2f95
> 2020-07-27 <<<12:59:29,948>>> [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.executor - Executing with the 'jdbc' executor
>
> 2020-07-27 12:59:29,966 [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.executor - Executing with the 'jdbc' executor
> 2020-07-27 12:59:29,975 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.changelog - Reading from XXX.DATABASECHANGELOG
> 2020-07-27 12:59:29,976 [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.executor - Executing with the 'jdbc' executor
> 2020-07-27 12:59:30,188 [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.util - Computed checksum for inputStream as 69be88e5a0af937fcecaeb79fb44811d

## Log with no delay(~ 4 seconds)

In normal times:

> :
> 2020-07-27 13:12:04,672 [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator - Loaded liquibase.diff.compare.DatabaseObjectComparator instance com.datical.liquibase.ext.storedlogic.StoredLogicComparator
> 2020-07-27 13:12:04,673 [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator - Loaded liquibase.diff.compare.DatabaseObjectComparator instance com.datical.liquibase.ext.storedlogic.checkconstraint.CheckConstraintComparator
>
> 2020-07-27 <<<13:12:04,676>>> [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.util - Computed checksum for 1595826724675 as 56c113e10add546ca00dadcb20c71635
> 2020-07-27 <<<13:12:08,966>>> [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.executor - Executing with the 'jdbc'
> executor
>
> 2020-07-27 13:12:08,979 [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.executor - Executing with the 'jdbc' executor
> 2020-07-27 13:12:08,988 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.changelog - Reading from XXX.DATABASECHANGELOG
> 2020-07-27 13:12:08,988 [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.executor - Executing with the 'jdbc' executor
> 2020-07-27 13:12:09,031 [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.util - Computed checksum for inputStream as 69be88e5a0af937fcecaeb79fb44811d

Any hint as to where the delay is coming from is appreciated.

## EDIT 1

After posting the question, it made me realize that i do not need this plugin:
<s>id 'org.liquibase.gradle' version '2.0.4'</s>

I have no idea if this is the cause of the delay, but i have just removed it.

## EDIT 2

The *~4 minutes delay* is not because of the plugin, it is still happening:

> 2020-07-29 08:49:06,074 [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.util - Computed checksum for 1595983746073 as 431beddb3aa3ca2d61f0c8b37185ae04
> 2020-07-29 08:53:14,902 [restartedMain] DEBUG liquibase.executor - Executing with the 'jdbc' executor