# Spring Boot - Liquibase - WebSphere - Cannot create filesystem for url file xxx/jsf-nls.jar

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

## Configuration

My Spring Boot/Liquibase specifications & configuration is as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135860/spring-boot-liquibase-takes-a-long-time60x-to-execute-occasionally).

## Issue

Everything goes well in my local environment with embedded Tomcat. When i migrate the war file to `IBM WebSphere 8.5.5.15`, i see this warning:

```
[7/29/20 11:04:17:302] 000002ff database      I liquibase.database  Could not set remarks reporting on OracleDatabase: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setRemarksReporting(boolean)
[7/29/20 11:04:18:066] 000002ff lockservice   I liquibase.lockservice  Successfully acquired change log lock
[7/29/20 11:04:18:090] 000002ff integration   W liquibase.integration  Cannot create filesystem for url file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar
                                 java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.<init>(ZipFileSystem.java:120)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:139)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:390)
    at liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.loadRootPaths(ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.java:63)
:
```

I have checked and the jar file is not there at the location that it is looking for it.

## Question

It's only a warning, everything else is working as expected, should i be concerned about this warning?

Comment: See:

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1276